# Using BeaufifullSoup to clean more the 300 hundred pages in the same time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a txt file from webget, with 300 html files inside. (`utf.txt`)

How can I clean it... i tryed Beautifulsoup, but it cleans just the first one. The tag that i need is "font".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("utf.txt", encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

print (soup.find_all('font'))
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! All that is left is to iterate though the files in the directory.

List out the files in the folder

```
import os
folder_with_files = "C://Users//zila//PMDB"  # from comments below
html_files = os.listdir(folder_with_files)

# With the list open each by doing the following

for file in html_files:
    with open(f’{folder_with_files}/{file}’ as fh:
        text = str()
        for line in fh.readlines():
            text += text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
          print (soup.find_all('font'))
```

Comment: Daniel Thank you. Could you explain this line with open(f’path/to/file/{file}’ as fp ?

Comment: `f’path/to/file/{file}’` is an f string. Essentially an easy way to format strings with variables. A quick google search will give a better explanation. The `path/to/file/‘` portion is just filler that to get to your files. Did that help?

Comment: I didn´t worked. The ('path/to/folder') is the same of  path/to/file/{file}’. I don´t know whats is getting wrong. @Daniel Butler, thank you very much.

Comment: I might not have read your answer thoroughly enough. How are all of the html files stored? Is it 300 websites on one file or is it 300 separate files?

Comment: It can be the two options. The wget program has an specific file. It is not an HTML, but if i rename as html  it´ll become an Html. The first line:<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="aui ltr" dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR" $container_height> <head> <title>

Comment: Ok so it’s not 300 different files it’s one file with 300 different html tags. If you have a way of sharing it with me I can see how to pull out the different html files. I originally read (incorrectly) that you had 300 separate files.

Comment: butlet. I have 300 diferent files or the content of these 300 in a unique file. Thank you.

Comment: With 300 unique files the original code will work as long as you point to the correct directory

Comment: I did with less files: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


import os
html_files = os.listdir('C://Users//zila//PMDB')

print (html_files) Results: ['410771', '410867', '410887', '410927', '411000', '411015', '411025']

Comment: for file in html_files:
    with open(f'(C://Users//zila//PMDB)') as fp:


File "<ipython-input-129-48b27ab980f5>", line 2
    with open(f'(C://Users//zila//PMDB)') as fp:
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Together: for file in html_files:
    with open(f'(C://Users//zila//PMDB)') as fp:
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

 File "<ipython-input-140-7d46eb390ac3>", line 4
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @Zila i've updated the script so you should be able to copy and paste it in. The Indentatiion error you are running into means that you have spaces and tabs mixed together. It tells you what line is the issue.